# git pull replaces existing code

Tags: git, git-pull, git-stash

After I committed files in Git, I made a `pull` request but it stops some of my code functionality. I want to go to the previous stage, before I committed my files, the state previous to this pull request.

I found `git stash` is an option to go to previous stage. But there are many options given with it like

```
git --rebase
git stash
git stash pop
```

Other commands I've tried include:

```
git status
git commit file1 file2 file3 -m "message"
git commit -i file1 file2 file3 "message"
git pull
git checkout
```

Which commands do I need to use to go to the stage before pull?

Comment: Please provide us with more details: What does it mean `it stops some o my functionality`? List your git commands and corresponding messages /errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `git stash` beforehand. If you didn't, you can try to guess your previous state by running `git log -g`.

Among the results find commits with "message". One of them is what you're looking for.

Comment: thank You Basin, Yes, there is list of all the commits i made. how can i go back now to previous stage using these commits.?

Comment: `git reset --hard <sha>`. e.g. `git reset --hard 5fa690e105116d8bd9f2539e30d83fad5c19d349`

Comment: Thanx Basin, this git command reset my code. and tokk me to the previous stage

Answer (score 2):

I think you mix *pull* and *pull request*. *Pull request* is a GitHub request to repository owner to grab some of your commits and apply those to his repository. `git pull` on the other hand is a process updating your local repository with new changes from the associated remote repository.

**WARNING:** *BACKUP YOUR LOCAL REPOSITORY FIRST.*

To recover from possible problems in your case you can try:

- `git reset --hard` reset on going merge process. This will remove all staged (`git add`ed) changes and all local changes.
- `git rebase --abort` reset ongoing rebase process, in case you started one issuing `git rebase` or `git pull --rebase`

After you cleaned up your repository I suggest, you do

```
git fetch
```

to make sure you are up-to-date with the remote repository. Then you can use `gitk --all` to visualize the history examining all branches. I suppose, you will see, that the `origin/master` branch is ahead of your local commits. In order to push your changes you will have to merge or better rebase. To do this checkout your local changes with

```
git checkout master
```

(replace `master` with your local branch) and then issue

```
git rebase origin/master
```

(replace `master` with your target remote branch). If you get merge conflicts you will have to resolve it, then `git add` changed files and then continue rebase process with

```
git rebase --continue
```

Now you can push your changes with

```
git push origin master:master
```

(replace `master` with your local branch and second `master` with your remote branch)

Comment: Thnax Boris Brodski, but can u please What these commands will do?

Comment: Thanx Boris Brodski, these commands works, but took me to the stage where i made last pull. Thanx

Comment: Please, update you question adding output of: git status, git branch -a, git show-branches --all

Comment: Boris Brodski, before receiving your comment i has been run those commands and was at ma previous stage. So i couldn't updated the question with the output